# Compartilhar com WhatsApp funciona somente com sistemas ANDROID?

Tags: html, whatsapp

Tenho o código HTML para compartilhar conteúdos do site no WhatsApp:

```
<a target="_blank" href="whatsapp://send?text=http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br">Compartilhar</a>
```

Só que ele apenas funciona no ANDROID quando tendo no Iphone ele não roda.

Answer (score 0):

funciona sim no IOS, até fiz no meu site, você só precisa corrigir esse seu link que está errado, dá uma olhada no meu código:

```
<a href=whatsapp://send?text=Olha%20esse%20link%20http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br>Compartilhar no WhatsApp</a>
```

o texto de chamada "olhe esse link" ou outro se for usar, deve ser colocado antes do link compartilhado, pois se for depois dá alguns erros em alguns dispositivos. esse é o código de compartilhamento do whatsapp, te aconselho a incluir em uma condicional para exibir apenas se o dispositivo for "mobile", e se quiser, podes usar as funções SERVER_NAME e REQUEST_URI para inserir o link de compartilhamento em todas as páginas automaticamente. outra dica é usar o "Eventos" do Google Analytics para mapear e acompanhar cliques e quem vem do whatsapp pra dentro de sua página.